# Deploy meteor project only as android app but not as a website

Tags: meteor

I am working on a project using meteor and I want to deploy it only as a web app but not a website, it there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. I guess you would probably like to know how. This is a very broad topic specific to your application, its users, and all of your needs. Do you have a specific question you can update us with?